# Cygwin SSH problem, unable to connect to local host, connection closed by 127.0.0.1

Tags: ssh, connection, cygwin, windows-server-2003

I have installed cygwin on a windows 2003 server, I added the openssh package, set up the neccesary enviroment variables, 
run the following commands

```
mkpasswd -l > /etc/passwd
mkgroup  -l > /etc/group
ssh-host-config
ssh-user-config
```

I've started the SSH service but when i run `ssh -v localhost` i get the following

```
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: Connection to localhost [127.0.0.1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/RLawton_P/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/RLawton_P/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1 
debug1: identity file /home/RLawton_P/.ssh/id_dsa type 2
debug1: identity file /home/RLawton_P/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.6
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.6 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatability mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSh-2.0-OpenSSH_5.6
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024(1024(8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'localhost' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/Rlawton_P/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowede by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey, password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/RLawton_P/.ssh/id_rsa
Connection closed by 127.0.0.1
```

can anyone advise what i need to do to get it working?

Comment: probably more appropriate on SuperUser/ServerFault...

Answer (score 0):

If you really need elevated privileges start cygwin shell with from an account with administrative privileges (XP) or r-click on cygwin.bat and "run as administrator" (Vista,Win7). That should olve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the same issue I saw on this post, [Public key authentication issues on cygwin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16627069/public-key-authentication-issues-on-cygwin/25651999#25651999).

You can verify by going into the next verbosity level when connecting,

```
# ssh -vv localhost
```

Answer (score -1):

When you installed Cygwin and ran ssh-host-config, you might have created user called "cyg_server". So when you are connecting to ssh, you need to use that user "cyg_server@localhost".

When you run ssh with that user, it will ask you for the password that you provided when you ran ssh-host-config.

$ ssh cyg_server@localhost
cyg_server@localhost's password:
Last login: Mon Dec 31 01:14:44 2012 from ::1
cyg_server@polorumpus ~
$
I hope it will be useful.